# How do I remove file extensions from a lot of files?

Tags: batch-file

I accidentally put a `png` extension to some files in a folder in git. How can I undo this action? Is there a git commit to do that?

Comment: Your question lacks elements of context. As such, it is difficult to understand, and hence to answer...  Is the folder containing those files managed by git (I'm assuming yes, given the way you ask, but that should be made explicit)? If so, did you commit the change (renaming to png)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
forfiles /S /M *.ext /C "cmd /c rename @file @fname"
```

Found [here](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.windows-commandline.com/rename-file-extensions-bulk/amp/).

This code renames all files in a folder and the subfolder recursivly when the command /S is used. The command /M defines the search mask to find the desired file type, which will be renamed. The /C defines that following code has to be executed on all desired files in a loop. More infos on the type of parameters can be found in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/forfiles).

Comment: Will this inform git of the name change? It would not work when using Subversion.

Comment: I would add all new files in a separate step after renaming

Comment: We are talking about `/S` option (which means to include subfolders). Using `@file` won't work because if a file is in a folder a level up, it won't be renamed. There is also a specific extension. Don't just copy code from an external source: modify it a bit.

Comment: You are right.I updated my answer with more information on how the command works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188993/discussion-between-michael-heath-and-double-beep).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `for /R` loop, where `/R` option is use to loop through all subfolders. In this case, it will loop through all subfolders, searching for files with extension equal to `png`:

```bat
@echo off

for /R "C:\folder\with\git" %%A IN (*.png) do ren "%%~fA" "%%~nA"
```

Or looping through a `dir` command which will search all subfolders for files with extension `png` (more secure because it excluded all directories with the `/A-D` option):

```bat
@echo off

for /F "delims= eol=" %%A IN ('dir /S /B /A-D "C:\folder\with\git\*.png"') do ren "%%~fA" "%%~nA"
```

Also, I would like to improve the `forfiles` solution posted by Johann above, checking if the item is a file and using full path to it:

```bat
@echo off

forfiles /P "C:\folder\with\git" /S /M *.png /C "cmd /c ren @fpath @fname"
```

For more info about the commands used, run the following commands to a new `cmd.exe` console:

- `for /?`
- `ren /?`
- `forfiles /?`
- `cmd /?`